# ¿Como programa crontab para ejecutar una tarea el ultimo dia del mes?

Tags: linux, crontab, gnu

Estoy buscando por ahí como programar una tarea para el último día del mes.
Pero encuentro soluciones retorcidisisimas como esta:

[code language="bash"]59 23 28-31 * * [ "$(date +%d -d tomorrow)" = "01" ] && execute_this[/code]

¡¡Tiene que haber una solución mas legible!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías desglosarlo para hacerlo un poco mas legible tal que:

```
# min  hr  date     month          dow
  59   23  31     1,3,5,7,8,10,12   * execute_this
  59   23  30     4,6,9,11          * execute_this
  59   23  28,29  2                 * execute_this
```

También podrías pasar la validación con date a un pequeño script y ejecutar:

```
59 23 28-31 * * check_date.sh && execute_this
```

Algunos crons, como Quartz, también implementan el flag "L", que representa al último día del mes, y se usa tal que:

```
0 59 23 L * execute_this
```

Fuente [Quartz:Special-characters](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html#special-characters)

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Genial!
¿Como se si mi cron implementa ese flag?

Comment: No hay una forma común para todas las distros, puedes buscar dentro de /usr/sbin/cron o /usr/sbin/crond si usas RH

Answer (score 2):

No es una solución retorcidísima, de hecho es una de las más sencillas, completas, concretas y elegantes.

Lo que quiere decir:

```
# min  hour day month dow  command
   01   00   *    *    *   [ "$(date +%d -d tomorrow)" = "01" ] && instruccion
```

Es sencillo, es

> Ejecuta cada tantos: minutos, hora, días del mes, meses, días de la semana, la siguiente secuencia de instrucciones

Y la secuencia de instrucciones se compone de dos: la primera es una validación que pregunta "Mañana es el día tal que es el 01?", ya que si mañana es el dia 01, **entonces hoy es el último día del mes**

Si pasa esa instrucción entonces dará verdadero y ejecutarán las siguientes instrucciones.

De esa manera no tienes que escribir todo lo que hizo @JoseVelasco para la parte con el `cron` tradicional.

El comando `date +%d -d tomorrow` utiliza el comando `date` para obtener el "día de mañana" (`-d tomorrow`) pero con el formato numérico del número del día (`+%d`), entonces, al comparar ese resultado con "01", estaríamos preguntando si "**¿Mañana es el primero del siguiente mes?**" que es equivalente a preguntar "¿**Es hoy el último día del mes**?".